# Using Qtwidgets with Qmake

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake, qtwidgets

I am building my Qt Application with `qmake -project` and `qmake Prog.pro`.

When I run the Makefile I get this error:

```
mainwindow.h:11:21: fatal error: QtWidgets: No such file or directory
 #include <QtWidgets>
```

I have to add the line

```
QT += widgets
```

To the .pro file to compile correctly. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this automatically?

Yes and no.

You could run qmake like this:

```
qmake -project "QT+=widgets"
```

and then it is generated properly, but other than that from the command line, no. Also, note that you would like to use a guard if you plan to support Qt 4, too:

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4):QT+=widgets
```

If you happen to use `QtCreator`, you will be able to avoid all this as the IDE will generate this all for you automatically.

Also, you should be able to avoid including the whole module with all the classes even though you do not use them all. So, instead of writing this:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
```

You could write:

```
#include <Foo>
#include <Bar>
...
```

Comment: @МикроПингвин: `qmake -project "QT+=widgets" "CONFIG+=c++11"` will work.